# CSS Transform or scale? Animate on mount

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

I'm trying to smoothly mount a component between two components. In this case, it would just display instantly.

How can I make it so that it would slowly ease in and scale height to the proposed height rather than just appearing?

I have a demo here:

[image: Edit lucid-star-fs6zi]

Comment: Because of the way React re-renders DOM elements, you'll need to use a special library to get CSS transitions to work properly with it. If you Google "React transitions" you can find many and choose the one you like best.

Comment: If you don't mind it being a little hacky you could use animations and transitions (and instead of mounting and un-mounting you will set the display to `none` and `inline`).

Answer (score 1):

As @IceMetalPunk in the comments already mentioned, you have to use libraries for that. For example `react-transition-group` would fit your needs.

I adjusted your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-tdd-7rvs8

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Button, Card } from "antd";
import { Transition } from "react-transition-group";
const CardExample = () => {
  const [showDiv, setShowDiv] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowDiv(!showDiv);
  };

  const cardStyle = {
    transition: `all 300ms ease-in-out`,
    background: "red"
  };

  const transitionStyles = {
    entering: { height: 150 },
    entered: { height: 150 },
    exiting: { height: 0 },
    exited: { height: 0 }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleClick} type="primary">
        Show Card
      </Button>
      <Card>ITEM</Card>
      <Transition in={showDiv} timeout={300}>
        {state => (
          <Card
            style={{
              ...cardStyle,
              ...transitionStyles[state]
            }}
          >
            This is my card
          </Card>
        )}
      </Transition>
      <Card>ITEM</Card>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <CardExample />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

**source:** https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition